# Facebook cron job

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make a simple Cron job, to post news on FB wall.

The problem I face is - user login is required. Tried few ways however cannot pass the login form (tried cURL but no success).

If user login is done manually, he can post a message, however I would need a job for this.
As I searched, I could not find anyone saying that they managed to post to FB wall from PHP.

So the question is:
Is it possible to perform cURL login/posting to FB wall. If answer is yes, would be nice to get some ideas how it must be done.

Comment: How about using oauth and saving the key so you can use the API?

Comment: Didn't work out for me. Have you tried inversivemedia and it worked for you?

Tried ~5 cases, however nothing could post automatically posts (required user login)

Comment: Here's a getting started guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/

It boils down to: create an app (very simple), getting authorization from a user to post on his wall, save the access token and use this token to post through the api (examples: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publishing-with-app-token/)

Comment: Tried this. However got the following error: the user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Comment: Do a manual log in as that user, authorize the app and use the token.

Comment: Here is the source of the code i tried http://madein.lt/dum/ex.txt

What do you mean by saying: Do a manual log in as that user, authorize the app and use the token? 

I follow instruction on fb page.

Comment: Additionally i tried the same using just pure wget and post from terminal, however it didn't give any good results as well. Additionally played with access from FB side. So any ideas would be welcome from the one's who have implemented such posting tool.

Comment: inversivemedia - any comments/ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **Extended Access Token**, documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/). You can call `/oauth` end point like following to retrieve Extended Access Token which is valid for 60 days. But it would still require you to refresh it after expiry.

```
oauth/access_token?  
grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
client_id=<YOUR_APP_ID>&
client_secret=<YOUR_APP_SECRET>&
fb_exchange_token=<PRESENT_SHORT_LIVED_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

**Update:-**
You need to first obtain a **short lived access token**, that you can get from [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) for your account after selecting your application from list of applications. If you want short lived access token for other generic users then you need to provide user a way to login, so that you may get the required value.
Then you need to retrieve the **Extended Access Token** and save it somewhere secure.
Then for every next action, you can pass this access token as the value for access token in your script to post on behalf of user.

Comment: `{
   "error": {
      "message": "No user access token specified",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
}`

Comment: You first need to authorize app so that you could retrieve `<PRESENT_SHORT_LIVED_ACCESS_TOKEN>` for the user on whose wall you want to post.

Comment: it is group wall. The user i'm trying to use can post all this information if i use php script where user manually first logins and then can post to wall.

Comment: @SauliusS Check my update above and reply if you face any problem

Comment: What do you mean by authorize @Anvesh Saxena? The user has access to my app, if i do manually without token, but first login with this user, then i can easily post to fb wall(login part cannot be in cron, therefore this way it fails)

Comment: @SauliusS .. By authorize I meant that User has logged into your app and connected/authorized it to perform operations on publishing permission. Were you able to retrieve Extended Access Token for your user ?

Comment: -Yes, user is authorized @Anvesh Saxena (i have developed another page, where first user logs in and than from page - one input field messages goes to fb). So my goal was to skip first step (user logging). Regarding token - no success.

Comment: Ok, I got that the user is authorized and you have the page access token and you are able to post to the page. But did you retrieve the **extended access token** for the user to continue your work even when he is not online? like for this cron job.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using offline access permission.

```
 $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope'=> 'email,publish_stream,user_hometown,user_location,user_photos,friends_photos,
              user_photo_video_tags,friends_photo_video_tags,user_videos,video_upload,friends_videos,offline_access,manage_pages',
            'redirect_uri'  => 'your redirect url'
        )
); 

 $user            =   null;
 $user       = $facebook->getUser();
 if (!$user) {       
    echo '<script> top.location.href="'. $loginUrl .'"; </script>';
 } else {
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
  }
```

/* store this access token into database by user id,  you can used this access token letter for posting on their wall */

Extending the expiration of existing short-lived user access_tokens ...
 Currently the long-lived user access_token will be valid for 60 days while the short-lived user access_tokens are currently valid from 1 to 2 hours. for more visit
https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: offline_access is not available any more.

Comment: So in case anyone has such a script, it would be interesting if you would contact me personally (as i don't see any new answers)

Comment: this is the site (http://hootsuite.com) that is mostly similar to my expectations (regarding posting news)